# modal view not showing inside didfinishpickingimage

Tags: iphone, image, modal-dialog, viewcontroller, picker

I have a viewcontroller, and I would like to display a modal view controller with :
presentModalViewController when a user finished picking an image.

The modal view controller is working fine when I call it from a button in my main view.
But when I call it from didfinishpickingimage callback nothing happens.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

before

```
[self presentModalViewController:MY_VIEW_CONTROLLER animated:YES];
```

Note the animated variable

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I decided to push the view controller I wanted to display after selecting an image onto my navigation controller instead of trying to present a modal view controller. It has the same effect as presenting a modal.

So I just did:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:MY_VIEW_CONTROLLER animated:YES];
```